# What does this component do?

Tags: semiconductors

I'm not good at electronics, so can someone tell me what [this component](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/FS/FSQ0170RNA.pdf) does?

Answer (score 6):

The device [FSQ0270](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/FS/FSQ0170RNA.pdf) is an integrated controller for [Switched Mode Power Supplies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched_mode_power_supply). The datasheet provides standard application circuit schematics.

When used in such a circuit, the device is fed with rectified mains voltage (unregulated DC half-sine wave), and generates the pulses required to drive a suitable transformer at 100 KHz, to provide a desired DC output voltage.

The Feedback pin accepts input from an optocoupler to sense the output current, and manipulates the output cycle-by-cycle (at each pulse, at 100 KHz i.e. 100,000 times a second) suitably to provide the designed voltage, with current limiting.

The part also has built-in safety features such as overload protection, overheat protection, and over- and under-voltage protection.

Some context on why the question was raised, would help provide a more relevant response.

Comment: So in laymans terms ...?                 Also there is no precise reason I asked the question, just wanted to know what it does.

Comment: @DavidL you should research a bit first: what is a power supply? What is a SMPS?

Comment: I think I understand it a little bit now. Maybe I will do some reading around this.

Comment: In layman terms, this device is the controller, the **heart** of an SMPS, **pumping** the power through in a precisely controlled way. The Wikipedia link provided in the answer would help understand how an SMPS works, and hence what such a controller is needed for.